# Button with image: remove background color

Tags: android

I'd like to have an image in a button with text and I've already have it. But the problem is that my image is with some " grey background colour" (as you can see below) that I would like to remove.

[image]

In a normal situation I would use `android:background="@null"` and it would solve it, but I'm using as background a template to my button.

```
<Button
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile_32"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow3"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/button_profile"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/buttonProfile"
        />
```

Does anyone know any other way to remove that grey background color from the image? Thanks.

Comment: is your actual image containing gray color? If then you can remove background with a photo editing software and export it as a png image.

Answer (score 0):

Is the grey actually part of the image? If not you could try background:"@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0):

If the grey background is part of the `profile_32` image, there is not an easy way to remove it in Android. You will need to have the image re-exported or use an image editing program to remove the background.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use an ImageButton and just add

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

or

```
android:background="@null"
```

to your Button.
The first 2 "0" is alpha, "00" = trasparent

Comment: He's using an image as background.